# How do I write the constructor here? C#

Tags: c#, oop

```
Computer.cs
class Computer    // parent class
    {
        public string a;
        public string b;        
        public Property(string a, string b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
Laptop.cs
class Laptop : Computer    // child class
    {
        public string y;
        public string b;        
        public Property(string y) // i dont know what comes here 
        {
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

Desktop.cs
class Desktop : Computer    // child class
    {
        public string x;    
        public string b;
        public Property(string x) // i dont know what comes here
        {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }
```

this.something = something <- something is a variable in the main program.
i dont know how the what i have to include in the constructor part.

Comment: Perhaps you need to read about [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)? *"A constructor is a method whose name is the same as the name of its type"* - not sure if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exercise you are doing is a good one in my opinion, good for learning how the inheritance works. The fix for your code should be like this:

```
abstract class Computer    // parent class
    {
        public string color;
        public string OwnerEmail;        
        public Computer(string color, string OwnerEmail)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.OwnerEmail = OwnerEmail;
        }
    }

class Laptop : Computer    // child class
    {
        public string trackpadDETAILS;
        public Laptop(string trackpadDETAILS, string color, string OwnerEmail)
            : base(color, OwnerEmail)
        {
            this.trackpadDETAILS = trackpadDETAILS;
        }
    }

class Desktop : Computer    // child class
    {
        public string mouseDETAILS;        
        public Desktop(string mouseDETAILS, string color, string OwnerEmail)
            : base(color, OwnerEmail)
        {
            this.mouseDETAILS = mouseDETAILS;
        }
    }
```

A working example for this is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XuhSdQ

Comment: if i were to call this how would i call it in the main loop. Im adding all the details to a list. is this correct? """ Computer.Add(new Laptop or Desktop(trackpaddetails or mousedetails, color, owneremail))""".

Comment: Okay, I'm adding an example of usage here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XuhSdQ

Comment: is there a way i can display all the data from my list? since i have 2 different types of objects i can't choose the mousedetails and trackpaddetails to show in for each loop. when i console.writeline i can only show the parent class fields like the color and the owneremail.

Comment: @user14186716 you need to cast them to their correct type. Like here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ZxpzL